# Date() javascript string inserted in DB showed in a pretty way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to print a date string stored in db with this format:
2016-09-13T18:18:08.518Z
into  a pretty way like this: 13 September 2016
thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean that the date is stored as text rather than an actual date?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular has a built in Date filter that can help you achieve any format you wish, as long as you store the date in a datetime field in your DB.

See the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

edit: The format you use to store the date is actually supported so you can actually use Date with your current format

edit2: Spelling mistake on help